# Mutliple people work on the same NiFi Dataflow

Tags: apache-nifi

How can teams located in different locations can work on the same NiFi dataflow at the same or different time?And how do we move each "only changes" in Dataflow to QA & UAT environments ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the approach is to organize the top-level canvas into process groups for each team that will be working on something. Then you can apply security policies to ensure that each group can only modify their respective process groups.

This post shows an example of how to secure an instance and setup policies for processor groups: https://bryanbende.com/development/2016/08/17/apache-nifi-1-0-0-authorization-and-multi-tenancy

Deploying flows between environments is an area currently being worked on by the community.

There is a feature proposal here that describes some of the planned capabilities: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Configuration+Management+of+Flows

There is a sub-project of NiFi called the registry which is where the work is being done:
https://nifi.apache.org/registry.html

Currently your options would be to export a template of a process group and import it into another environment. You could script a lot of this by using the REST API. Anything you can do from the UI can be done through the REST API which is easy to see by opening something like Chrome Dev tools and watching the requests being made while using the UI.